# Why is UIImage? nil here?

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm trying to bridge React and Swift code by passing a string for an image path, which I've verified appears correctly on the Native side, and having a bit of an issue. The image path comes from React as NSString, and my goal is to pass that as a String to a Native function that will ultimately send data back to React.

Here's a snippet of some code that handles part of this

```
classifyImage(value as String)
```

and some of the body of the classifiyImage is as follows:

```
 @objc func classifyImage(_ image: String) {
    let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: image, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData)


    guard let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(
            rawValue: UInt32((uiImage?.imageOrientation.rawValue)!)) else {
      return
    }
    ...code
}
```

The exact error is at the line with the rawVale, reading
`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here's more info if it may help...

[image: Debug area]

Image data can come from the camera as such `image    NSMutableString "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/54691469-2196-444E-9B45-C0D6F2CABEBC/Library/Caches/Camera/EEC3631C-3E96-44DA-B258-411363A2F10C.jpg"    0x00000002815a8420`

or from the phone's gallery `image    String  "ph://8F109DC0-CE95-4D0A-9D11-1B2E9CE6B8D3/L0/001"`

Comment: It's because you're using a URL string instead of the image itself.

Comment: How do I refer to the image itself?

Comment: The accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674591/base64-string-to-uiimage?rq=1 Worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Image from a file

First, we need to turn the string into a URL, then the URL into data like so:

```swift
let url = URL(string: image)
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
    print(e)
}
```

Then we can use it to create the image.

```swift
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    guard let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(
            rawValue: UInt32(image.imageOrientation.rawValue)) else {
      print("that didn't work")
      return
    }
} catch {
    print(e)
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately still doesn't work for the path from the phone.

Comment: I found a solution, you can see it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909390/react-native-how-to-get-file-asset-image-absolute-path/68600045#68600045